# changing UIBarButtonItem UIButton's image

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uinavigationbar

I have a UIBarButtonItem with a custom view of a UIbutton with an image, I want to have a different UIImage for different orientation, so here's my code:

```
 UIButton * backButton = (UIButton *) ((UIBarButtonItem *) self.navBar_.topItem.leftBarButtonItem).customView;
        if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]) && IS_IPAD) {        
            [backButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back-landscape.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];  
            [backButton setFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 46, 35)]; 
        } else {
            [backButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back-reading.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];  
            [backButton setFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 23, 19)]; 
        }
```

However this doesn't change the UIButton image, why is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:-

```
UIButton * backButton ;
if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]) && IS_IPAD) 
{ 
    backButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 66.0f, 36.0f)];       
    [backButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back-landscape.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];  

} 
else 
{
    backButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 23, 19)];     
    [backButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back-reading.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];  
    [backButton setFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 23, 19)]; 
}

[backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(goToHome) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *HomeButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView: backButton];
[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:HomeButton];
```

Comment: this isn't changing the UIBarButton it is just creating a new one

Answer (score 1):

You should notify that you say it is a  `UIBarButtonItem` , but you use  `UIButton` in code.

From ios5.0, you can use `UIAppearence Protocol` to change  `UIBarButtonItem`  background image, like:

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackgroundImage: forState: barMetrics:]
```

You can also use elppa's method, but notice you can directly use `UIImageView` for the `customView` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the new proxy class with +appereance method check the DOC, but is only for iOS5. For earlier support you can update the image while the view is rotating the view controller method -willRotateToInterfaceOrientation.
Ciao

Comment: viewWillRotate is where the method above is at. but it isn't working

Comment: Try to call [self.view setNeedsDisplay]; at the end of the method. Are you calling super in -viewWillRotate

Answer (score 0):

Create a UIBarButton using a custom UIButton:

```
_optionsButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[_optionsButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"menu2.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_optionsButton addTarget:self action:@selector(optionsButtonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIBarButtonItem * optionsItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:_optionsButton];
```

Then set a background image as you would normally for that UIButton (instead of trying to change the image for the UIBarButton).

```
[_optionsButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"keyboard.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

This worked great for me

Note: When I was going through this I was changing the picture depending on what the current picture was. I found I had to use:

```
if ([[_optionsButton imageForState:UIControlStateNormal] isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed: @"keyboard.png"]]) {
    // Code for the certain button function 
}
```

to get it to work